# Replacing keys for 09 Malibu

Tags: key, chevrolet, malibu

I bought my 09 Malibu used and was given only one set of keys.  I've lost them and now the dealership is telling me it will cost about $900 to replace them because the lock system was installed aftermarket and they have to replace it also.  Any suggestions about a way to do this cheaper?  I don't have ignition key, door key or key fob.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a one of the big locksmith companies in town, I'd try them.  There's a number of options that may be available to them that might not be to the dealer.

Answer (score 1):

Is there another dealership close by? I would get a second opinion on the price. Also, when you ask them, don't tell them you lost all of the keys. Just say you need a spare and you don't have your main key with you. Sadly they may jack up the price if they know you are in a bind.